# Include a container from main() in a class method

Tags: c++

I have a container that HAS to be in main(), but I also need to include it in the method for a class that has its own .h and .cpp files.

My code in main has this:

```
vector<lex> words;
vector<lex>::iterator it;
```

My method pulls words from a file with a comma as a delimiter. Every time a delimiter is hit the word is pushed into the lex:

```
string temp;
lex *f1;
f1 = new lex;

ifstream tofill( "filler.txt", ios::out );
if( tofill.eof() )
    cout<<"Empty File";
else if( tofill.is_open() )
{
    while( !tofill.eof() )
    {       
        getline( tofill, temp, ',' );
        f1->setWords( temp );   
        list.push_back( *f1 );
```

And the method to show the data from the container:

```
for( it = list.begin(); it != list.end()-1; ++it )
{ 
    it->showWords();
}
```

This code works if I make a new .h file and place the containers in it, and include it in the lex.cpp but I am unable to include the container in a method from main(), is  there a way that I can include the container from main() in a class method?

Comment: What do you mean by "include the container in a method"?

Comment: Please could you post all your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you pass the vector by-reference?

```
class Foo {
    void someMethod(std::vector<lex>& words);
}

void Foo::someMethod(vector<lex>& words) {

    words.push_back( (lex()) ); 
}
```

Usage:

```
vector<lex> words;

Foo foo;
foo.someMethod( words );
```

Or by-pointer (if `nullptr` has meaning in your application, as references shouldn't be null):

```
class Foo {
    void someMethod(std::vector<lex>* words);
}

void Foo::someMethod(vector<lex>* words) {

    if( words != nullptr ) {
        words.push_back( (lex()) ); 
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
vector<lex> words;

Foo foo;
foo.someMethod( &words );
```

Comment: I think I should be done with code for today... Thanks, you helped me!